# Printing a string using a pointer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, printing, char

I am trying to print a string read into the program from the user.

I **need** to be able to print the string by *using* a pointer.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    char *pstring = &string;
    printf("The value of the pointer is: %s", *pstring);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a **segmentation fault**

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: `*pstring` is the value of the char that pstring is pointing to. Use `pstring` without dereferencing it. That is: pass the address contained in pstring to printf() not the first character of the user's string. The **segfault** is because printf has been handed rubbish and tries to find a string at some unpredictable address.

Comment: This should generate a compiler warning about mismatched types. If not, enable more warnings, especially `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually take an address of an array, it's either `&string[0]` or just `string`.  In the `printf()` for `%s` you should pass a `char` pointer not a `char` (which is what `*pstring` is).  It's a good idea to add a newline to the `printf()` format string as `scanf()` doesn't pass that along:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%99s", string);
    char *pstring = string;
    printf("The value of the pointer is: %s\n", pstring);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` IS a pointer. A constant one.

It is worth understanding what arrays are (compared to pointers).

And specifically the difference between those:

```c
char *str1=malloc(6);
strcpy(str1, "hello")
char str2[6];
strcpy(str2, "hello");
```

In this example, `str1` and `str2` are both pointers.
But `str1` is a variable (like "int x": x's value is stored in memory and you can modify it). Whereas `str2` is not. It is a constant, like `12`. It looks like a variable, because it is an identifier (`str2`), but it is not. Once compiled, there is no place in memory to store str2 value. The compiler computes its value, at compile time, and in the generated machine code, this value is inserted directly in the code. Exactly like for "12".

So `str2=malloc(6)` for example, or `str2=whatever` would make no sense. No more than typing `12=6` or `12=whatever`. It is not a variable. It is a constant value.

And likewise, `&str2` has no sense neither. No more than `&12` has. It would be asking the address where a constant is stored. But a constant is not stored anywhere. It is a value directly in the code.

Namely str2 is a constant value of an address where the compiler has reseved enough room for 6 bytes. So you can store things in str2[0], str2[1], ..., str2[5], but not in str2 itself (again, it is a constant value, not a variable. You cannot store things in it, no more than you can store things in `12`)

Situation for str1 is different. str1 is a variable, declared as type `char *`. You can store values of type `char *` in it (that is pointers to a char, that is memory address where a char is stored). And that declaration affect a default (initial) value to this variable, which is the address of 6 bytes, containing the letters 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and the terminal 0.

So, you can easily change str1, and store whatever pointer you want in str1. Writing `str1=str2` for example.

So, long story short: both are pointers. str2 is a constant pointer, but still a pointer. Both are address of a place in memory where the first, then second, etc, char of the string are stored.

So, in your case, just type

```c
char *pstring=string
```

or use `string` directly.
Or, for aesthetic purpose, to clarify that you mean "address of the first char of string", you may type

```c
char *pstring = &(string[0])
```

which is the exact same thing as "string" (in C, syntax `a[b]` is just a shortcut to `*(a+b)`, so `&(string[0])` is `&(*(string+0))`, which is `&*string` which is `string` (another strange consequence of that, is that you could as well say

```c
char *pstring = &(0[string])
```

again, that just means `&(*(0+string))`

Note that I advise none of those strange writing. But it helps understand how pointers are just values, that you may store in variables (like with str1) or use directly as constant in the code (like with str2). It is just less obvious than for integers (`x` a variable declared as `int x=12;` vs `12` that a constant) because in case of arrays (constant pointers) those values are named by the compiler and take the concrete appearance of an identifier in the code.